# Native Query not hydrating scalarResult

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I tried to execute this snippet of code without result:

```
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM People ppl WHERE ppl.email= ? AND 
                (ppl.cod_etb=3 OR ppl.cod_etb IS NULL)";
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addScalarResult('count','count');
$query= $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $email);
var_dump($query->getResult());
```

I know there is a problem with the resultSetMapping because this code is working and giving me the right entity :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM People ppl WHERE ppl.email= ? AND
                (ppl.cod_etb=3 OR ppl.cod_etb IS NULL)";
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($this->_em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('my\myBundle\Entity\People', 'ppl');
$query= $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $email);
return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

But after a lot of searches I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, the documentation on this is really poor, and the examples I've came accrossed are all same as mine and working trusting their authors.

Links I mentionned :

[at the end of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340789/return-foreign-key-with-dql-query)

[subject is not the same, but he is using a similar query which works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099286/telling-doctrine-how-to-format-datetime-when-using-native-query-and-resultsetmap)

Edit : 
With a `var_dump($query);` I see that the `$query` is well constructed, but I found those lines :

```
public 'scalarMappings' => 
    array (size=1)
      'count' => string 'count' (length=5)
  public 'typeMappings' => 
    array (size=1)
      'count' => string 'string' (length=6)
```

As far as I understand, it tells that count will be stored in a string right? Whereas it is an integer... Is that a normal behaviour?

Edit 2 : For the moment I have done a "hack" with a [statement](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=37872) but I don't like that solution so still hoping someone could find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

$query->getSingleScalarResult()

Comment: Already tested, returning null... I might be wrong but I think given the fact that getResult() is more general if getSingleScalarResult gives the result, getResult() will give it too...